# flycheck cannot enable python-flake8 configuration file not found

Tags: python, flycheck

I'm trying to set up flycheck to run flake8 on my python files. I'm using pipenv so I set up `flycheck-python-flake8-executable` for my buffer to point to the virtual environment version of flake8 and it seems to be detected. However it refuses to enable the checker. Running `flycheck-verify-setup` gives me

```
  python-flake8 (disabled)
    - may enable:         yes
    - executable:         Found at /Users/gmauer/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-name-qFaGhtMo/bin/flake8
    - configuration file: Not found
```

So I try to enable it with `flycheck-disable-checker` and...nothing, nothing output to messages, no errors, same verify-checker output.

I thought that maybe it has to do with the fact that it can't find a configuration file but I have a valid `.flake8` file in both my user root and in my project so I have no clue why its not detecting it.

```
[flake8]
exclude = .git,__pycache__,docs/source/conf.py,old,build,dist,node_modules,instance
```

I can run it just fine from eshell.

What could be wrong? What else do I do to debug?

Comment: do you enable `flycheck-mode` or have a hook for enabling it on .py files in your .emacs?

Comment: @manandearth yes, flycheck-mode is enabled and showing up as enabled. I've also tried toggling it

Answer (score 5):

You can set the path to your flake8 configuration with: 
`(setq flycheck-flake8rc "/path/to/your/flake8-config-file")`

As for enabling there are different ways of doing it I prefer to use an `add-hook` like so: `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)`

You can also set it up globally with: `(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)`.

Comment: Cool, thanks, got that set, and I *do* have flycheck enabled and am trying to enable the checker but it never seems to get enabled. When I select it directly it just says `Flycheck cannot use this syntax checker for this buffer.` I _do_ see an issue on their tracker about this now that I've gotten past this point https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/1437