# Flycheck cannot use this syntax checker for this buffer

Tags: spacemacs, flycheck

I use spacemacs and while in Python mode, flycheck can not use flake8 checker even when I try to manually enable it using `flycheck-disable-checker`. I get the following output from `flycheck-verify-checker flake8` (colors annotated):

```
Syntax checker in buffer code_v1.py in python-mode:

  python-flake8 (disabled)
    - major mode:         (green) `python-mode' supported
    - may enable:         (green) yes
    - executable:         (green) Found at /home/user/.virtualenvs/xxx/bin/flake8
    - configuration file: (green) Found at "/home/user/.config/flake8"

(red) Flycheck cannot use this syntax checker for this buffer.

Flycheck Mode is enabled. Use SPC u C-c ! x to enable disabled checkers.

--------------------

Flycheck version: 32snapshot (package: 20181018.1021)
Emacs version:    25.2.2
System:           x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Window system:    x
```

Further output:

```
(xxx) user@host:~$ which flake8
/home/user/.virtualenvs/xxx/bin/flake8
(xxx) user@host:~$ flake8 --version
3.6.0 (mccabe: 0.6.1, pycodestyle: 2.4.0, pyflakes: 2.0.0) CPython 3.6.7rc1 on Linux
```

Why can't I enable the flake8 checker? What causes **`Flycheck cannot use this syntax checker for this buffer.`**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41653/flycheck-cannot-enable-python-flake8-configuration-file-not-found  Try manually setting `flycheck-flake8rc`.

Comment: @ebpa thanks, but that didn't help, see updated question.